# Batch convert .rar terminal

Tags: convert, batch

I need to batch convert a bunch of .rar files to .zip files in a folder. I do not need to extract them they are comics help in .rar form and I want to convert them to .zip so they can be used in calibre.

Comment: FWIW, you do need to extract them in order to zip them. This isn't like converting a .docx into an ODF format :)